# Seperating review and description from eachother

Tags: magento-2.1

I want to separate the description tab and the review tab from eachother on my website. Where can I do this and how do I do this? Cannot figure out which code to edit.

https://www.thefixedgearshop.com/fietsen/state-bicycle-fixie-fiets-core-line-beorn.html

Comment: So you want to remove the review tab and put the reviews elsewhere?

Comment: @harri I want to move it below the description. In a seperate section.